# How do I pull the whole XML tag when comparing richtextboxes?

Tags: vb.net

I have a program that loads xml files into richtextboxes and is supposed to compare them. The differences between the two files is then spit out into a third richtextbox. I used the method shown in [this SO post from 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22113098/comparing-words-in-two-richtextbox-to-find-difference). It works as far as loading the difference between the files into the third textbox. However, I was wondering if anyone could help me get the entire related XML tag to show instead of just the single line.

[I would like the whole XML tag to show instead of just the one line highlighted here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5XzI.png)

[This is the result I'm getting of the comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uakhm.png)

This is the code I used from the above mentioned post.

```
 Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Dim txt1(RichTextBox1.Text.Split(" ").Length) As String
    Dim txt2(RichTextBox3.Text.Split(" ").Length) As String
    txt1 = RichTextBox1.Text.Split(" ")
    txt2 = RichTextBox3.Text.Split(" ")
    Dim diff1 As String = "" 'Differences between 1 and 3
    Dim diff2 As String = "" 'Differences between 3 and 1
    For Each diff As String In txt1
        If Array.IndexOf(txt2, diff.ToString) = -1 Then
            diff1 += diff.ToString & " "
        End If
    Next
    For Each diff As String In txt2
        If Array.IndexOf(txt1, diff.ToString) = -1 Then
            diff2 += diff.ToString & " "
        End If
    Next
    RichTextBox4.Text = diff1 & diff2
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this a software you're writing for yourself because you haven't found a good option to compare XML files?

Comment: If you want to compare XML, I'd strongly recommend to work with it as DOM objects (e.g. using XElement and friends) rather than trying to do some kind of naive text comparison.  I think the application of the earlier SO post is different enough that it's not useful as a reference.