# Comparing text in two Richtextboxes and get the differences

Tags: vb.net, loops, compare, richtextbox

I'm want to compare the text between two **richtextboxes** and get the differences in the third one. Without highlight the text. 
So far, the best option is [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22113098/comparing-words-in-two-richtextbox-to-find-difference?answertab=active#tab-top)

The first solution works, but it doesn't remove the text present in richtextbox2 from the richtextbox1.
Endeed, the user asked

> if they are the same do nothing.

My case is complete the opposite and still i cannot find a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to add a combobox to your form named (combobox1)
then add these items in it:

RichTextbox1 - RichTextbox2

RichTextbox2 - RichTextbox1

second, add a button named (button1), under this button click event
insert this code:

```
RichTextBox3.Clear()
If RichTextBox1.Text <> "" And RichTextBox2.Text <> "" And RichTextBox1.Text <> RichTextBox2.Text And ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "RichTextbox1 - RichTextbox2" Then
    Dim txt1(RichTextBox1.Text.Split(" ").Length) As String
    Dim txt2(RichTextBox2.Text.Split(" ").Length) As String
    txt1 = RichTextBox1.Text.Split(" ")
    txt2 = RichTextBox2.Text.Split(" ")
    Dim diff1 As String = ""
    For Each diff As String In txt1
        If Array.IndexOf(txt2, diff.ToString) = -1 Then
            diff1 += diff.ToString & " "
        End If
    Next
    RichTextBox3.Text = diff1.ToString
End If

If RichTextBox1.Text <> "" And RichTextBox2.Text <> "" And RichTextBox1.Text <> RichTextBox2.Text And ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "RichTextbox2 - RichTextbox1" Then
    Dim txt1(RichTextBox1.Text.Split(" ").Length) As String
    Dim txt2(RichTextBox2.Text.Split(" ").Length) As String
    txt1 = RichTextBox1.Text.Split(" ")
    txt2 = RichTextBox2.Text.Split(" ")
    Dim diff2 As String = ""
    For Each diff As String In txt2
        If Array.IndexOf(txt1, diff.ToString) = -1 Then
            diff2 += diff.ToString & " "
        End If
    Next
    RichTextBox3.Text = diff2.ToString
End If
```

now, you have 2 options:
if you choose (RichTextbox1 - RichTextbox2) from the combobox then click the button, richtextbox3 will display the text which is found in richtextbox1 and not found in richtextbox2, while if you choose (RichTextbox2 - RichTextbox1), the opposite will happen

finally, if the 2 richtextboxes is the same, nothing will occur

- Also you could use String.Join *

Under Button1 click event replace this code with the previous one:

```
Dim intsA = RichTextBox1.Text.Split(" ")
Dim intsB = RichTextBox2.Text.Split(" ")
Dim myresult = intsA.Except(intsB).ToArray()
RichTextBox3.Text = String.Join(" ", myresult)
```

if you found this useful, mark it as answer

Comment: Hi GME, thanks. Unfortunately, your code will work perfectly comparing 2 singles line of text.
I'm looking ot replace words from rtb1 in rtb2 doesn't matter their position. If "X" is contain in the beginning of rtb1 but in the end of rtb2, then I want it to considerate it and eliminate it. Id like to eliminate everything exhisting from rtb1 to rtb2. Hope it's clearn. THX

Comment: do you think its possible to do that?

Comment: i'm not sure that i understand you well, for example i took your comment above and gave that a quick try, first i copied it to the 2 richtextboxes and press the button (no result), then i removed the word (contain) after ( If "X" is) from the second box only (the result is the removed word contain), then i added the word contain again but at the end of the paragraph in box 2 (the result is nothing again), the code works perfectly for your idea, if you still need modification please give me an example of the text you want to process and i will edit the code for you.

Comment: Hi @GME , thanks for your answer. I'll try to be more specific letting images to talk. 
[link](https://imgur.com/a/rVD3ZlY)

Comment: p.s. also C5 is not in the same line of A4, so it should be in the line below.

Comment: @raskitchen please look at the edited last part of my answer, and give that method a try

Comment: Dear @GME , Thanks for you code, unfortunately im reporting those bugs. Almost same of the other code. [link](https://imgur.com/a/GaUsoZ1).
Surfing around i found the magic WinMerge, but i really don't know how to implement this on my code.. I thought it was easy but it's starting to be harder than i though. link for winmerge [link](https://winmerge.org/)